# Como eu pego o nome de um input

Tags: javascript

***Exemplo:***

```
<input type="text" name="peixe">
```

Como eu consigo o nome peixe???

***Observação:*** javascript puro

Comment: O que você quer exatamente? a sua tela só vai ter esse input? se sim

Comment: Você quer obter "peixe"? Sendo assim, se o input tivesse outro nome, você receberia esse outro nome? Ou quer obter o valor do input a partir do nome peixe?

Comment: AKU e consegiu resolver?

Answer (score 7):

A maneira mais recomendada em pegar o nome seria com [getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/document/getElementsByTagName), ***exemplo***:

```js
var nomes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
console.log(nomes[0].name);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="peixe">
```

porque, é mais suportados pelos navegadores:

- Google Chrome 1
- IE 6
- Firefox 3
- Safari 3
- Opera 5

***Nota:*** o [getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/document/getElementsByTagName) nesse caso em especifico pega todos os elementos `input`, ou seja, um `array` de informações, no caso da pergunta só tem 1 então `nomes[0].name` retorna o nome desse `input`, se tiver 30 `input` vai retornar um `array` desses 30. Talvez falte um contexto melhor, mas, do jeito que está na pergunta isso é o que precisa.

---

Tem um outra forma que é com [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), exemplo:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('input').name);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="peixe">
```

e os navegadores suportados são:

- Google Chrome 1
- Firefox 3.5
- IE 8
- Opera 10
- Safari 3.2

<sub>***Referencia:***</sub>

- [Document.getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/document/getElementsByTagName)
- [HTML DOM getElementsByTagName() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp)
- [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: Seria interessante essa resposta ser usada como referência pois tem um suporte quase nativo, mas em relação a simplicidade poderia ser editada ;)

Comment: Não entendi @FelipeDuarte?

Comment: Não é maneira mais simples, e sim a mais recomendada...

Comment: @FelipeDuarte realmente já editada

Answer (score 2):

Você também pode usar [queryselector](/questions/tagged/queryselector)

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("input").name)
```

```html
<input type="text" name="peixe">
```

### Definição e Uso

O método `querySelector()` retorna o primeiro elemento que corresponde a um seletor **CSS** especificado no documento.

> **Nota**: O método `querySelector()` apenas retorna o primeiro elemento que corresponde aos seletores especificados. Para retornar todas as correspondências, use o método `querySelectorAll()`.

Se o seletor corresponder a um **ID** no documento que é usado várias vezes (Observe que um "id" deve ser exclusivo dentro de uma página e não deve ser usado mais de uma vez), ele retorna o primeiro elemento correspondente.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que a maneira mais simples seria com `querySelector`, para vários elementos poderia usar o `querySelectorAll`...

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('input').name);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="peixe">
```